# Как получить дочерние категории при помощи Criteria?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria

Существует сущность Category, описанная следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта сущность описывает категории товаров для сущности Gift.
В данный момент для получения всех gift'ов с определенной категории я использую следующий предикат в Criteria:

```
builder.equal(gift.get("category"), filter.getCategory());
```

Но соль в том, что мне необходимо получить не только список gift'ов данной категории, но и всех её дочерних категории. В голову приходит следующая конструкция:

```
gift.get("category").in(values);
```

Вопрос: как вместо values получить массив всех дочерних категории, включая основную категорию?

Comment: Добавлю, что подразумевается неограниченное кол-во вложенных категории. Но не думаю что их будет больше 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом:

```
String subQuery = """
                    WITH RECURSIVE temp1(id, parent_id) as (
                    SELECT t1.id, t1.parent FROM category as t1 WHERE id = ?
                    UNION
                    SELECT t2.id, t2.parent FROM category as t2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON(temp1.parent_id = t2.id))
                    SELECT id FROM temp1
                    """;
            List<Long> categories = entityManager.createNativeQuery(subQuery, List.class)
                    .setParameter(1, filter.getCategory().getId())
                    .getResultList();
            predicates.add(gift.get("category").get("id").in(categories));
```

Справедливо для **Postgres**